# PHP loading data from external URL with nonstandard port

Tags: javascript, php, curl

A solar monitoring system generates a page at http://68.37.209.78:8050/ with live performance data. I want to scrape and parse this data, pass the PHP variables to JavaScript variables, which I can feed into HighCharts to make pretty graphs.

So far, I've managed to find out how to use PHP to read an external file, by using file_get_contents() or fopen(). It appears that neither of these functions will work if it's a nonstandard port I'm trying to access, as is the case here. I found an alternative method using cURL():

```html
<?php
$cURL = curl_init('http://68.37.209.78'); //Initialise cURL with the URL to connect to
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_PORT, 8050); //Set the port to connect to
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 8050); //Get cURL to return the HTML from the curl_exec function
$HTML = curl_exec($cURL); //Execute the request and store the result in $HTML

echo $HTML; //Output the HTML
?>
```

When I try to run this, the page doesn't seem to want to even load. If I change the URL to some arbitrary address, and change the port to 80, the script works great. Where did I go wrong??

Comment: Did you try to init the curl without http:// ? Did you check if the curl libraries are loaded on your environment?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I tried it without http://, and it still did not work. I know that the curl libraries are loaded because I can substitute http://www.google.com for the URL and specify port 80, and sure enough, it echoes the text from the site.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Add this and see what happens: `if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}`

Comment: The environment I'm using is Bluehost. Does that shed any light?

Comment: I suppose they could be blocking that port. Can you set up a php instance locally and try?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can access that port from your server? Try running this command in your console, should be the same for Linux or Windows:

```
curl -i -XGET http://68.37.209.78:8050

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Wed, 13 May 2015 23:39:55 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Power Panel 1.2 (Solar2X5B.js)
(C) W/M^2--(C)-- L/M
OAT PYRA HXI HXO FLW
 21   55  16  22   3

       SIGN       TEMP(C) W/M^2 (%) (A) (%) (A) STATS -----LEVEL-----
ID SOH  dBm VERSN PNL TNK Sgain PNL PNL TNK TNK PL TK PLH PLL TKH TKL HT
01   1  -89  1.48  15  19    52   0   0   0   0 04 00  0   0   0   1   0
02   1  -93  1.48  16  27    17   0   0   0   0 04 00  0   0   0   1   0
03   1  -82  1.48  18  23    35   0   0   0   0 24 00  0   0   0   1   0
04   1  -95  1.48  16  20    48   0   0   0   0 1C 1C  0   0   0   1   0
```

Perhaps there are some firewall rules blocking your access.
You can use curl -v for even more verbose debug output.

http://curl.haxx.se/download.html <- curl for various platforms

Comment: Good suggestion! May be curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 8050); needs to be changed to curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 80);

Comment: Are you saying that if port 8050 is blocked in my server environment, it won't work?

In any case, I tried entering the code you indicated, and nothing. When I changed it to curl -i -XGET http://www.google.com, I got a whole bunch of stuff spit back out at me.

Comment: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is just a boolean, not a port number.

Comment: Update: I just checked, and it would appear that port 8050 is closed for BlueHost.

Note that http://68.37.209.78:8050 is not on BlueHost. The page where I'm trying to make the charts is on BlueHost. 

Would that still matter?

Comment: I think you should contact your hosting provider or read some FAQs
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/152
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/405
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/426#ports

Comment: Tell me if I understand this correctly. If port 8050 is blocked on my BlueHost server, and I have created a script running on the BlueHost server that is trying to access port 8050 on an external site, the connection will be blocked?

Comment: Yes, they have probably blocked most outgoing ports which will stop your script from connecting to the outside world. But if I understood their website correctly, you might be able to ask them to open up that port for you.

Comment: Whoah, I was just able to load the site using <iframe>. Now if I can figure out how to load the data from the iFrame into JavaScript variables, I'm set!